# Is there a CVS client for Mac OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, subversion

Could anyone recommend me a free tool to use on OSX for keeping my CVS projects?

I am using the integrated SVN on OSX for all my SVN projects; maybe there are similar commands on the terminal to access a CVS repository.

Comment: I don't use raw CVS or SVN with GUI (but Versions is perfect), I use it within my IDE when I develop something. So you can try Xcode or IntelliJ Idea (I use it only under evaluation licence, Community Edition is completely free) . fast search over Internet shows that most of CVS viewer projects are dead (last version is PPC), but you can recompile them to use it with your OS.

Answer (score 6):

I have /usr/bin/cvs, which has been installed together with Xcode; albeit, it might be Xcode 3.

just doing a check the file is still here under Mavericks and Xcode 5 and I have done clean upgrade since the original answer

Comment: Indeed, that should be all you need for command-line interactions.  Are you looking for a GUI?

Comment: if you know something good i would also consider using a gui for this one...